# How to share a typescript function from a react project with a common html website?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I want to share a complex typescript exported function to a simple HTML - javascript website

I tried to use npm tsc to transform the file into javascript, but generated files have "exports" functions that creates errors in the browser console.

myFunction.ts

```js
export const getTest = (test: any) => {
    // Change test object
    return test;
};
```

generated myFunction.js

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.getTest = function (test) {
    // Change test object
    return test;
};
```

Browser console actually warning me "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined" when I try to include the file with a script tag in HTML file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the original `myFunction.ts` file all you need to do is this:

Remove the typing and change the extension to `.js`:

```
export const getTest = (test) => {
    // Change test object
    return test;
};
```

And then, in your HTML file's `<script>` tag for that JavaScript file, make sure you set the `type` attibute to `module` like so:

`<script type="module" src="myFunction.js"></script>`

Finally, you'll need to `import` that functionality where you intend to use it.

That should do it as long as you consider browser compatibility:

[ES6 Modules](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module)

To make this ultimately clear, here is a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6sy1JuVTJPo4DF7K87Lm?p=preview) to demonstrate what I mean.

Answer (score -1):

The `export` keyword creates a module, which can only be used with a module system (such as webpack).

Either use a module system or drop `export` to create a normal file that creates global names.

Comment: Webpack is not a module system. The export/import are straight ES6 syntax. All the OP has to do is remove the TypeScript specific content. The generated javascript is not useful.